# Cannot change version of project facet dyanmic web module 3.0 to 2.5

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, java-6

I saw lot of similar questions was asked for change the dynamic web module.
But still I am unable to find perfect solution. I’m very new to Java J2EE.

I need to import war project in to my eclipse workspace and need to deployed on local tomcat6.

**This is step i used:**

1. Import war file
2. Open the Build Path in project Java  and import JRE System Libray[jdk1.6.0_45],all WebContent\WEB-INF\lib in to build path
3. In project Java Compiler set as JDK compliance as 1.6
4. Add tomcat6 server in to the eclipse servers
5. Try to set Dynamic Web Module 3.0 to 2.5 in project facets that gave me Java 1.5 or newer error. Please refer the below image for more details

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
 <!-- Servlets -->
```

[image: Project facets]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse IDE is this?

Comment: Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200

Comment: Your web.xml snippet says 2.4..

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes is that not equal to "dyanamic web module" 2.4?

Comment: Question is about 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

My english is not good.

You can switch view to Naviator in eclipse, try using the following steps:

1. open your project
2. open .settings directory
3. open org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

now you can change jdk version and web version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.5"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

Comment: thanks your feed back. I need to set java 1.6 and jst.web 2.5. could you explain little more why i can't change via eclipse GUI.

Comment: I can not answer your question. but I think change via eclipse GUI maybe can not change the settings. This problem you can go and ask the eclipse community

Answer (score 0):

Go to project, right click and choose build path then configure build path
then click project facets, here you will see many options on right side,
choose "dynamic web module" and choose the version you need and click "apply" and "OK"

Comment: as discribe in question i was tired to change same way. but gave to me "Java 1.5 or newer" error